# RTSP Streaming not starting automatically in PyQT5 QMediaPlayer

Tags: python, pyqt5, qmediaplayer

I am using this code to display RTSP stream.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl, QSize
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFileDialog, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, 
        QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSlider, QStyle, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QStatusBar)

class VideoPlayer(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoPlayer, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)

        btnSize = QSize(16, 16)
        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()

        openButton = QPushButton("Open Video")   
        openButton.setToolTip("Open Video File")
        openButton.setStatusTip("Open Video File")
        openButton.setFixedHeight(24)
        openButton.setIconSize(btnSize)
        openButton.setFont(QFont("Noto Sans", 8))
        openButton.setIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("document-open", QIcon("D:/_Qt/img/open.png")))
        openButton.clicked.connect(self.abrir)

        self.playButton = QPushButton()
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.playButton.setFixedHeight(24)
        self.playButton.setIconSize(btnSize)
        self.playButton.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.positionSlider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, 0)
        self.positionSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setPosition)

        self.statusBar = QStatusBar()
        self.statusBar.setFont(QFont("Noto Sans", 7))
        self.statusBar.setFixedHeight(14)

        controlLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        controlLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        controlLayout.addWidget(openButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.playButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.positionSlider)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(videoWidget)
        layout.addLayout(controlLayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.statusBar)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.mediaStateChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.durationChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.error.connect(self.handleError)
        self.statusBar.showMessage("Ready")

    def abrir(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Selecciona los mediose",
                ".", "Video Files (*.mp4 *.flv *.ts *.mts *.avi)")

        if fileName != '':
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
                    QMediaContent(QUrl("rtsp://192.168.1.206:554/live/0/SUB")))
            self.playButton.setEnabled(True)
            self.statusBar.showMessage(fileName)
            self.play()

    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def mediaStateChanged(self, state):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
        else:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))

    def positionChanged(self, position):
        self.positionSlider.setValue(position)
       
        print(position)
    def durationChanged(self, duration):
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, duration)
        
        
    def mediaStatusChanged(self, status):
      self.statusBar.showMessage("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())
            
    def setPosition(self, position):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)

    def handleError(self):
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.statusBar.showMessage("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoPlayer()
    player.setWindowTitle("Player")
    player.resize(600, 400)
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It's showing the RTSP stream correctly. But because of the network, if the camera stops for few seconds, it doesn't restart streaming automatically. I tried to print the position on line 90. But the value of position keeps on increasing even when the camera stops.
How do I know if the status of stream ie frames are coming or its stopped?

Comment: Welcome to the site, you might get a better response if you ask a question in your post.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added my question now. Please check.